# Spring Data JPA + Hibernate Skip Locked rows - Oracle SQL

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to do a job on multiple threads that selects and updates records in an Oracle database. Do to this, I want to select each row individually, do some work and then mark it as done (by updating
the status column on the record).
In order for the threads to not select the same record, I want to lock it and instruct the others to SKIP any locked rows at selection.

What I have right now for selecting the row and locking it is this (Using Spring JPA) :

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = AvailableSettings.JAKARTA_LOCK_TIMEOUT, value = "-2"))
Optional<Customer> findFirstByStatusOrderByIdDesc(String status);
```

The problem is, the resulting sql looks like this :

```
select c1_0.id,c1_0.first_name,c1_0.last_name,c1_0.status from customer_db c1_0 
where c1_0.id in(select c1_0.id from customer_db c1_0 where c1_0.status=? order by c1_0.id desc fetch first ? rows only) 
for update skip locked
```

And all the threads when  they run the inner sql :

```
select c1_0.id from customer_db c1_0 where c1_0.status=? order by c1_0.id desc fetch first ? rows only
```

they get the same id result (the largest) so they all try to select the same record and, because the SKIP LOCK feature works, only one of the threads is able to obtain a record, the others don't get anything.

How can I modify the query - by use of spring Jpa preferably, so that I can distribute the work between my threads as intended.

I am using Java 17 and Spring Boot 3.1.2

Comment: Write the query yourself, so that you don't have that inner select but just 1 select.